# Trying to use zap in a gitlab-ci workflow

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, zap

I am  trying to automatize the usage of Zap in the continuous integration workflow of my company. We are using gitlab-ci and I'd want to use a docker image embedding Zap as a service and, in a first time, just call a quick scan on a legally targetable website like itsecgames.com.

I am using the docker image [nhsbsa/owasp-zap](https://hub.docker.com/r/nhsbsa/owasp-zap/) that exposes zap.sh as entry point.

#### My question is:

*How can I use this image as a service in a gitlab-ci YAML script in order to do a quick scan on itsecgames.com?*

#### Relevant information:

Here is my gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: openjdk:8-jdk

variables:
  PROJECT_NAME: "psa-preevision-viewer"

stages:
  - zap

zap-scanner:
  services:
    - nhsbsa/owasp-zap:latest 
  stage: zap
  script:
    - nhsbsa__owasp-zap -cmd -quickurl http://itsecgames.com/ -quickprogress
```

When the gitlab runner tries to resolve this job, I get this error message:

```
$ nhsbsa__owasp-zap -cmd -quickurl http://itsecgames.com/ -quickprogress
/bin/bash: line 27: nhsbsa__owasp-zap: command not found
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

At this point I've tried different approaches like calling zap.sh directly instead of nhsbsa__owasp-zap, or nhsbsa-owasp-zap (according to [gitlab-ci documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#accessing-the-services), both names should work though).

There probably is something that I'm seriously misunderstanding, but isn't using a service in gitlab-ci the same as pulling an image and calling docker run on it on my own computer ? As a matter of fact if I use

```
docker run nhsbsa/owasp-zap -cmd -quickurl http://itsecgames.com/ -quickprogress
```

I get as expected an XML with the found vulnerabilities.

If that's important:

- gitlab-runner version is 1.11.1
- gitlab version is Community Edition 8.7.4

Comment: It might be worth raising an issue on https://github.com/nhsbsa/owasp-zap ? Or you could ask the maintainer directly - their email address is in the Dockerfile: https://github.com/nhsbsa/owasp-zap/blob/master/Dockerfile

Please post back if you find out the answer, I'm interested to know :)

Comment: Right, I mailed the maintainer and yep I'll post it here if he answers me :)

Comment: `nhsbsa__owasp-zap` is the name of the host, you can ping, you can configure it as a proxy to it but you can't run it as a local command.

Answer (score 3):

When you create a service in gitlab it spins up the docker container alongside and gives you a hostname in which to access it. The idea is you call your commands from the initial docker image and point them to your service image. As @Jakub-Kania mentioned it doesn't allow you to run it as a local command.

So in terms of our nhsbsa/owasp-zap image it means we have a owasp-zap daemon running and available at nhsbsa__owasp-zap:8080. We then use maven and the zap plugin to scan our application.

Something like this (we're also parsing the zap results in sonar) :

```
mvn -B --non-recursive -Pzap -DzapPort=$NHSBSA__OWASP_ZAP_PORT_8080_TCP_PORT -DzapHost=$NHSBSA__OWASP_ZAP_PORT_8080_TCP_ADDR
  -DzapTargetUrl=$baseUrl
  -DsonarUrl=$SONAR_URL  -Dsonar.branch=release
  br.com.softplan.security.zap:zap-maven-plugin:analyze sonar:sonar
```

Depending what you're application is written in you might want to run the docker run command as a script step rather than using a service.

@Simon Bennetts is there a way to use something like curl to pass a test request to a remote zap daemon?

Comment: You can use the [zap cli](https://github.com/Grunny/zap-cli) to control Zap from a remote host. This includes starting a scan, parsing the results etc.

Comment: Many thanks for the insight :) I copied your example without the part about sonar, but I still can't get it to perform the analysis I'd want to. I added the corresponding profile to my pom.xml following the example of [the corresponding GitHub page](https://github.com/pdsoftplan/zap-maven-plugin).

I get this error :
`[INFO] Starting ZAP analysis at target: http://itsecgames.com
[ERROR] Error creating a new ZAP session.
br.com.softplan.security.zap.zaproxy.clientapi.core.ClientApiException: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server`

Any idea of a possible cause ?